# Uploaded img not delete after update on laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is my update code of laravel 5.4 version. All is working except the file is not delete which is previously uploaded.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $input = $request->all();
    if ($request->hasFile('userpic')) {
        $userpic = $input['pic'];
        $file_path = public_path("avatars\$userpic");
        if(File::exists($file_path)) {
            File::delete($file_path);
        }
        $fileName = time().$request->userpic->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->userpic->move(public_path('avatars'), $fileName);
        $input['userpic'] = $fileName;
    }    
    Product::find($id)->update($input);
    return redirect()->route('productCRUD.index')->with('success','User updated successfully');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php **unlink** function check here[function.unlink.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Do like this

```
unlink($file_path);
```

Comment: in `$file_path` do you have full path like this **avatars/image23.jpg**

Comment: After edit like this its working. Thanks to you Sahoo ji     

$file_path = public_path("avatars/$userpic");
            if(File::exists($file_path)) {
                File::delete($file_path);
            }